# Is it possible to create a web automation without using tags like css, id, class or xpath?

Tags: python, automation, web-applications, rpa, webautomation

I'm trying to create an automation that will do simple tasks, like clicking and inputting. But my problem is that the application that will "recieve" the automation is extremly old and doesn't have objects, so the buttons don't have an id or class.

The owner of the app doesn't want to update it to help us with automations, so my code will have to deal with this.

I need the automation to run in the background, which means that any framework that needs a GUI is useless.

Does anyone know whether this is possible?

I tried using `selenium`, but it couldn't even find the buttons or input fields using XPath.

I tried to use `pyautogui` too, but it needs a GUI, rendering it useless for our purpose.

Comment: you can search for all buttons, then loop over them to find the one with the text you want.

Comment: Please provide more information about the app you are trying to automate. We need to know what you're working with to provide accurate information. You mentioned a webapp, what sort of webapp is it, if applicable?

Comment: Its a ERP web. I cant provide a link cause its local bynow. Which type of information would you need? Im sorry im an begginer @amycodes
About the loop, how could I do that if the text inserted in the button its a span?

Comment: Right, well without the website source or detailed information about it, it will be exceedingly hard to develop a solution. The easiest way to go about website automation is a controllable browser, which selenium offers. The next best thing is to interact with their API, if they have one.